Complex dynamic classical control over integer field with Qiskit's Expr
Hi I have read this tutorial, where it used expr to customize classical control for long-range CNOT:
for i in range(num_ancilla_pair):
    qc.measure(2*i + 2, cr1[i])
    if i == 0:
        parity_target = expr.lift(cr1[i])
    else:
        parity_target = expr.bit_xor(cr1[i], parity_target)

with qc.if_test(parity_target):
    qc.x(-1)

Basically what it does: XOR all the measurement results stored in cr1, and apply X gates based on the XOR result parity_target.
I had checked the document of expr, and it seems that currently it only supports simple computation like XOR, NOT, OR, shift, etc.
Now I have more complex classical control, e.g.: cr1[0:2] + 2 * cr2[0:2] >= 3, where +,* is integer addition and multiplication, and cr1[0:2] represents an integer. Can we achieve that by expr?
One way out I think is to convert the inequality over integer field into binary field s.t. we can use expr to implement the expression. E.g. cr1[0:2] = (cr1[0] << 1) XOR cr1[1]. Theoretically with these operations we can do any dynamic classical controls, but it is tedious.
Do we have simple ways to implement it, or existing tools to do such conversion? How do you deal with similar complex dynamic classical controls? Thanks very much for your reply!

The expression cr1[0:2] + 2 * cr2[0:2] >= 3 can be converted into the Boolean expression:
cr2[1] | (cr1[0] & cr1[1]) | (cr1[0] & cr2[0]) | (cr1[1] & cr2[0])
which can easily be translated into a Qiskit classical expression:
from qiskit.circuit.classical import expr

_condition = expr.bit_or(
    expr.bit_or(
        expr.bit_or(
            cr2[1], expr.bit_and(cr1[0], cr1[1])
        ),
        expr.bit_and(cr1[0], cr2[0])
    ),
    expr.bit_and(cr1[1], cr2[0])
)

with circ.if_test(expr.equal(_condition, True)):
    circ.x(qr[4])

In general, you can follow the below procedure to construct a Qiskit classical expression from a mathematical expression:

Modify the expression to use Clbits. For example, replace cr1[0:2] by (cr1[0] + 2 * cr1[1])
Write down a truth table and evaluate the expression for all possible values of the classical bits.
Use the truth table to deduce the DNF of the expression.
(Optionally) use sympy to simplify the DNF.
Use the DNF to construct the Qiskit classical expression.

It's not hard to automate this procedure. First we use sympy to build and simplify the Boolean expression:
import re
import sympy

def _truth_table(n):
    if n < 1: return [[]]
    sub_table = _truth_table(n - 1)
    return [row + [v] for row in sub_table for v in [0, 1]]

def _bits_to_vars(str_expr):
    return re.sub(r'(\w+)\[([0-9]+)\]', r'\1_\2', str_expr)

def _vars_to_bits(str_expr):
    return re.sub(r'(\w+)_([0-9]+)', r'\1[\2]', str_expr)

def get_boolean_expression(str_expr):
    str_expr = _bits_to_vars(str_expr)
    original_xpr = sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr(str_expr)
    num_variables = len(original_xpr.free_symbols)
    xpr = False
    for assignment in _truth_table(num_variables):
        values = dict(zip(original_xpr.free_symbols, assignment))
        if original_xpr.subs(values):
            clause = True
            for symbol in original_xpr.free_symbols:
                clause &= symbol if values[symbol] else ~symbol
            xpr |= clause
    print('Boolean Expression:', _vars_to_bits(str(xpr)))
    smpl_xpr = sympy.simplify_logic(xpr)
    print('Simplified Boolean Expression:', _vars_to_bits(str(smpl_xpr)))
    return smpl_xpr

Then, we recurse through the expression tree and build the equivalent Qiskit classical expression step by step:
from qiskit.circuit.classical import expr

def _get_bit(arg):
    _bit_var = str(arg).split('_')
    # Here we assume that classical registers are defined in the global scope
    return globals()[_bit_var[0]][int(_bit_var[1])]

def get_qiskit_condition(smpl_xpr):
    for _index, or_arg in enumerate(smpl_xpr.args):
        if or_arg.func == sympy.Symbol:
            _sub_condition = _get_bit(or_arg)
        else:
            for _idx, and_arg in enumerate(or_arg.args):
                if and_arg.func == sympy.Symbol:
                    bit = _get_bit(and_arg)
                else:
                    bit = expr.bit_not(_get_bit(and_arg.args[0]))

                if or_arg.func == sympy.And:
                    _sub_condition = expr.bit_and(_sub_condition, bit) if _idx > 0 else bit
                else:
                    _sub_condition = expr.bit_or(_sub_condition, bit) if _idx > 0 else bit

        if smpl_xpr.func == sympy.Or:
            _condition = expr.bit_or(_condition, _sub_condition) if _index > 0 else _sub_condition
        else:
            _condition = expr.bit_and(_condition, _sub_condition) if _index > 0 else _sub_condition

    return _condition

We can use it as follows:
smpl_xpr = get_boolean_expression('cr1[0] + 2 * cr1[1] + 2 * (cr2[0] + 2 * cr2[1]) >= 3')
_condition = get_qiskit_condition(smpl_xpr)

with circ.if_test(expr.equal(_condition, True)):
    circ.x(qr[4])

This method should work with more complex expressions. For example,
smpl_xpr = get_boolean_expression('sin((cr1[0] + 2 * cr1[1] + 4 * cr1[2]) / 8) + cos((cr2[0] + 2 * cr2[1] + 4 * cr2[2]) / 8) >= sqrt(2)')
_condition = get_qiskit_condition(smpl_xpr)

Note, however, that it does not scale beyond few classical bits.

Thanks very much for your reply! Your method is really inspiring! Let me give it a try
